# Hiding and displaying information based on section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

My scenario is as follows. I have 7 tabs (one for each day) using bootstrap. I would like to have all 7 days worth of information loaded upon pageload.

```
<ul class='nav nav-tbs'>
  <li><a id='monday'>Monday</a></li>
  <li><a id='tuesday'>Tuesday</a></li>
  <li><a id='wednesday'>Wednesday</a></li>
  <li><a id='thursday'>Thursday</a></li>
  <li><a id='friday'>Friday</a></li>
  <li><a id='saturday'>Saturday</a></li>
  <li><a id='sunday'>Sunday</a></li>
</ul>
```

Idealy, upon clicking a days tab you're only shown that days information. Each 'daily page' is fairly complex.

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='span12'>
    <legend>Breakfast</legend>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='row'>
  <div class='span5 bfood'>
    <h3>{{ bname }}</h3>
    <img src='{{bimg }}'>
    <ul>
      {% for ing in bing %}
      <li>{{ ing }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='span6'>
    <div class='well'>
      <form>
        {{ csrf_token }}
        <h2>Doesn't sound good?</h2>
        <p>
        <h3>Breakfast Food:</h3>
        <input type='text' value='{{ bfood }}' id='bfood'>
        </p>
        <p>
        <h3>Breakfast Required:</h3>
        {% for breq in br %}
        <div class='input-append'>
          <input type='text' name='br' value='{{ breq }}'>
          <button class='btn btn-danger rmv'><i class='icon-minus'></i></button>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button class='btn btn-success add' id='br'><i class='icon-plus'></i></button>
        </p>
        <p>
        <h3>Breakfast Forbidden:</h3>
        {% for bfor in bf %}
        {% if bfor != '' %}
        <div class='input-append'>
          <input type='text' name='bf' value='{{ bfor }}'>
          <button class='btn btn-danger rmv'><i class='icon-minus'></i></button>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <button class='btn btn-success add' id='bf'><i class='icon-plus'></i></button>
        </p>
        <button class='btn new-recipe' id='b'>Try again</button>
        <div id='result'></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='span12'>
    <legend>Lunch</legend>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='span5 lfood'>
    <h3>{{ lname }}</h3>
    <img src='{{ limg }}'>
    <ul>
      {% for ing in ling %}
      <li>{{ ing }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='span6'>
    <div class='well'>
      <form>
        {{ csrf_token }}
        <h2>Doesn't sound good?</h2>
        <p>
        <h3>Lunch Food:</h3>
        <input type='text' value='{{ lfood }}' id='lfood'>
        </p>
        <p>
        <h3>Lunch Required:</h3>
        {% for lreq in lr %}
        <div class='input-append'>
          <input type='text' name='lr' value='{{ lreq }}'>
          <button class='btn btn-danger rmv'><i class='icon-minus'></i></button>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button class='btn btn-success add' id='lr'><i class='icon-plus'></i></button>
        </p>
        <p>
        <h3>Lunch Forbidden:</h3>
        {% for lfor in lf %}
        {% if lfor != '' %}
        <div class='input-append'>
          <input type='text' name='lf' value='{{ lfor }}'>
          <button class='btn btn-danger rmv'><i class='icon-minus'></i></button>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <button class='btn btn-success add' id='lf'><i class='icon-plus'></i></button>
        </p>
        <button class='btn new-recipe' id='l'>Try again</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='span12'>
    <legend>Dinner</legend>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='span5 dfood'>
    <h3>{{ dname }}</h3>
    <img src='{{ dimg }}'>
    <ul>
      {% for ing in ding %}
      <li>{{ ing }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='span6'>
    <div class='well'>
      <form>
        {{ csrf_token }}
        <h2>Doesn't sound good?</h2>
        <p>
        <h3>Dinner Food:</h3>
        <input type='text' value='{{ dfood }}' id='dfood'>
        </p>
        <p>
        <h3>Dinner Required:</h3>
        {% for dreq in dr %}
        <div class='input-append'>
          <input type='text' name='dr' value='{{ dreq }}'>
          <button class='btn btn-danger rmv'><i class='icon-minus'></i></button>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button class='btn btn-success add' id='dr'><i class='icon-plus'></i></button>
        </p>
        <p>
        <h3>Dinner Forbidden:</h3>
        {% for dfor in df %}
        {% if dfor != '' %}
        <div class='input-append'>
          <input type='text' name='df' value='{{ dfor }}'>
          <button class='btn btn-danger rmv'><i class='icon-minus'></i></button>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <button class='btn btn-success add' id='df'><i class='icon-plus'></i></button>
        </p>
        <button class='btn new-recipe' id='d'>Try again</button>
        <div id='result'></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What would be the best strategy to hide/show each of the above? As a side note, I'd also like to reduce the complexity of the 'single' page, as it's rather long and has a lot of repeat stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap each bunch of day code in an element, like...

```
<div id="section_monday">
  //all code for monday
</div>
```

then use JQuery like so...

```
$(".nav nav-tbs").find("a").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   var id = "section_" + $(this).attr("id");

   $("#" + id).toggle();//will turn sections on/off with each click
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery it's easy to just [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/), [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) or [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) any element on your page.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do the following:

1. Make functions for every content repeating so you have a "cleaner" code
2. would also reduce workload if you need to change something in one of the segments
3. put the content of every day into a seperate div and upon load just show the div of the current day or something that fits your needs
4. Then when clicking toggle show hide on the div's needed

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `.toggleClass( function(index, class, switch) [, switch] )`

`function` returns class names to be toggled in the class attribute of each element in the matched set.

`switch` A boolean value to determine whether the class should be added or removed.

Here the full documentation http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/